# Nodejs как soket client

Tags: node.js, websokets

Как можно на NodeJS подключится к soket'у и слушать его? т.е сервер будет выступать в качестве клиента, возможно для этого есть модули для Nodejs но я почему-то не нашёл про это информации.

Comment: Речь о простом socket-соединении или конкретно о websocket?

Comment: Об websocket соединении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Как написано в документации пример:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/', {
  protocolVersion: 8,
  origin: 'http://websocket.org'
});

ws.on('open', function open() {
  console.log('connected');
  ws.send(Date.now().toString(), {mask: true});
});

ws.on('close', function close() {
  console.log('disconnected');
});

ws.on('message', function message(data, flags) {
  console.log('Roundtrip time: ' + (Date.now() - parseInt(data)) + 'ms', flags);

  setTimeout(function timeout() {
    ws.send(Date.now().toString(), {mask: true});
  }, 500);
});
```